# The answer given for this has taken the case of non repetition . What will be the answer if repetition is allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer given for this has taken the case of non repetition. What will be the answer if repetition is allowed?[image: problem_statement]

Comment: ${9\choose 1}{8\choose 3}{5\choose 3}{2\choose 2}\cdot 26\cdot 26^3\cdot 10^3\cdot 33^2$

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I agree with Hagen - 2,508,140,194,560,000

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Makes sense completely. Thanks Hagen .